# Filter by multiple sub-document keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The following document was expected to be trapped by the filter applied below - but it does not.
What could be the issue?

// Sample document.

```
 Document emp2 = new Document();
    emp2.put("name", "Charlotte Evelyn");
    emp2.put("website", "webcodegeeks.com");

    Document emp2_addr = new Document();
    emp2_addr.put("addr_line1", "Fremont, AK USA");
    emp2_addr.put("zip_code", "19408");
    emp2.put("address", emp2_addr);
```

Filtration

```
            documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.match(eq("address.zip_code", "19408")),
                    Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("address.addr_line1", "USA"))));       
            listDoc = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Document doc : documents) {
                listDoc.add(doc);
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listDoc.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here:

- I believe you should put all your filters in one `match` instead of two different ones. It doesn't change the result of the query but may help using indices in the future (only the first `match` will use indices).
- In the second filter you try to match exactly (`eq`) the value `"USA"`, but the address that you entered in `address.addr_line1` is `"Fremont, AK USA"`. I believe you might have more luck using a `regex`.
  Hope this helps.